# Error when installing Json.Net to a project targeting Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, json.net, nuget

I tried installing Json.Net via NuGet using the command `install-package newtonsoft.json`.

I got an error like the one shown below.  How can I resolve this?

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'.
Removing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3' from ReadJSON.
Successfully removed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.3' from ReadJSON.
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6' to ReadJSON.
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files 
that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Have you tried to contact the package author?

Answer (score 2):

Support for Windows Phone 7 and Silverlight 4 was removed from Json.Net in version 6.0 ([source](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support)).  If you still need to target WP7 / SL4, then you will need to use Json.Net v5.0.8 instead.  You can install this by using the following command in the Package Manager console:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 5.0.8
```